# Install Ruby 2.1.1 / Rails 4.0.4 on CentOS 6.5

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm, chef-infra

Here my recipe:

```
execute "rvm-install" do
  user "root"
  command "curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby=2.1.1"
  action :run
end
```

... PASS

```
%w{ruby-devel rubygems}.each do |pkg|
  package pkg do
    action :install
  end
end
```

... PASS

```
execute "gem-update-system" do
  user "root"
  command "gem update --system"
  action :run
end
```

... PASS

```
execute "ruby-1.9.3-install" do
  user "root"
  command "rvm install 1.9.3"
  action :run
end
```

... FAIL

```
 * execute[ruby-1.9.3-install] action run
================================================================================
Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[ruby-1.9.3-install]'
================================================================================


Errno::ENOENT
-------------
No such file or directory - rvm install 1.9.3
```

... ultimately I'd like to do this

```
execute "rails-install" do
  user "root"
  command "gem install rails 4.0.4 -V"
  action :run
end
```

I have tried passing `--rails` in my `rvm-install` but that failed miserably.

Hope I can get some help.

Comment: RVM takes more configuring than I can see happening in your script. Have you looked into [`chef-rvm`](https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rvm)?

Comment: Note that RVM is installed, I can run the command from my terminal, it's just Chef that is not able to execute that command. I did try to use chef-rvm, but I wasn't able to do much with it either (most likely do my inexperience).

Comment: MY current work around was to give the full path to RVM: `/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm install 1.9.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chef never loads the user environment by default, so the $PATH (or $HOME) is not available when the command runs. The best you can do is to specify the full path of the command that you want to run and, if you need some environment variables to be loaded, you can do that with this command:

```ruby
execute "Executing a command with ENV variables" do
  command "/tmp/foo.sh"
  user "MY_USERNAME"
  environment ({ 'HOME' => ::Dir.home('MY_USERNAME'), 'USER' => 'MY_USERNAME', 'FOO' => 'BAR' })
end
```

See: https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-2288

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @daniel's answer it might be useful to source the RVM script in a wrapper script so your whole environment is up to snuff (`.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemsets` files being honored for example)

```
#!/bin/sh
source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm
/path/to/my/super/awesome.sh
```

k